# Cannot seem to recover my privatekey Or import my wallet on blockchain why? help

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-import

Help, i was running bitcoin and i saw this error message popup saying...f.cloud.github.com/assets/4311082/448597/… what could be causing this and how can i fix it?
*Update*I fixed it by backing up the files uninstalling and reinstlling.

but now im trying to figure out my privatekey because i heard you can transfer coins from your address with it. but everytime i go in debug window and type in

00:42:22
￼
dumpprivkey <...>

it says

00:42:22
￼
Invalid Bitcoin address (code -5)
i replaced my address with three dots but why is it saying that? i go check my wallet in blockchain and it works there it says i have money and everything...

Also when i try to import my wallet.dat file in https://blockchain.info/wallet/import-wallet it keeps saying Wallet decrypter returned empty response when i dont enter a password

and it says Unexpected end of file from server when i type in the password at the end...what could be causing this? why cant i find out my privatekey? help please!!!